# wx.SearchCtrl problems in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am developing an application in python using the graphic library wxpython.
I want to add a serchbox (searchctrl). In the picture you can see the application without searchbox and then with the searchbox in the Display area

[image]

As you can see the table of the display area got smaller. In order to set the searchbox at the right side I just used:

```
ButtonBoxDosSizer.AddSpacer(99)
```

It is 99 because for this value the searchbox is set where I want it. I just tested some other values until I came to that one.

Does anybody knows why the table got smaller or pulled down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    sz = ButtonBoxDosSizer
    # ...
    sz.AddSpacer(99)
```

in comparison to that:

```
    sz.AddSpacer((99, -1))
```

[The docs](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Sizer.html#Sizer.AddSpacer) are not so clear about what is allowed for parameter `size`, but it seem clear for me from the doc, that `size` if given as `int` means both height **and** width. And a size tuple component of `-1` will leave this dimension to the sizing process.